# Update a certain part of page but without UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a Page consist of 5 different usercontrols with texboxes, dropdownlist according to the backend table requirement and a submit button. The task is to save the fields in database without postback means just like update panel but without it. Each usercontrol has do this without postback. I don't know what to do...

Comment: Update panel reply's are really slow...

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try jQuery Ajax. Refer these links,

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example)